# Unable to parse [resolvepath(parameter('CommerceEngine-Ops_CommerceEngineWdpFullPath'))]

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation, commerce-engine

I'm trying to install Sitecore Commerce v9.2 with SIF.
I installed Sitecore Experience Platform v9.2 and updated the installation script. After I run the .\Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1 on the elevated mode in Powershell, I'm getting this error below.

```
[----------------------------------------------------------------------------- CommerceEngine-Ops_InstallWdpSOLR : WebDeploy -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
VERBOSE: Resolving ConfigFunction extension 'resolvepath'
VERBOSE: Resolved 'Invoke-ResolvePathConfigFunction'
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Unable to parse [resolvepath(parameter('CommerceEngine-Ops_CommerceEngineWdpFullPath'))] - Exception calling "InvokeWithContext" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' 
because it is an empty string."
At C:\deploy\Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1:93 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Verbose *>&1 | Tee-Object "$PS ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:34
GetConfigFunctionResult : Unable to parse [resolvepath(parameter('CommerceEngine-Ops_CommerceEngineWdpFullPath'))] - Exception calling "InvokeWithContext" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because 
it is an empty string."
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Private\JsonConfiguration.ps1:226 char:20
+ ...      return GetConfigFunctionResult -FunctionText $InputObject -Param ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,GetConfigFunctionResult
```

Comment: In your Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1 file, there is a parameter "CommerceEngineWdpFullPath", please check if the value for this parameter is resolving to correct file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not sure about this field `"XCInstallRoot" = ".."`, I thought the value will be extracted in the script. Also, the installation documentation did not mention about this field. So I kept the default value. 
After I updated this field to `[string]$XCInstallRoot = "c:\deploy"` this issue was solved.